XCode 16.1 Build Fails on react-native-job-queue: Command SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface failed with a nonzero exit code
We have a pretty old React Native mobile app I am trying to build on XCode 16.1.  It built fine previously on XCode 15.
Now I get a failure on build, only on the react-native-job-queue method of:
Command SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface failed with a nonzero exit code
Nothing has changed anywhere in the code.  It just stopped building once I was upgraded to XCode 16.1.  I can't downgrade XCode as I'm on MacOS Sequoia.
I've also tried the 'workaround' to run older XCodes and even that fails.  I've tried XCode 14.3 and XCode 15.  Both crash on load of the project.  I'm guessing thats because I'm on Sequoia as they refuse to install telling me they don't support my MacOS version.
Has anyone found a workaround or fix for this issue?
Here is a copy of the Podfile if it helps:
platform :ios, '17.4'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'


target 'myapp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'CTPanoramaView' #, '~> 1.2'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

  use_native_modules!
  # use_frameworks!

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.74.0' })

  post_install do |installer|
    # flipper_post_install(installer)

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

      if target.name == "React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources"
        target.remove_from_project
      end

      target.build_configurations.each do |config|

        config.build_settings["ENABLE_BITCODE"] = "NO"
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '17.4'
        
      end
    end
    
  end
end



